# Storing passwords with different hash types in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, hash

I'm planning to move my website to **Laravel 7** framework, but many users already have passwords set and I don't know which hash type was used.

Should **Laravel** be able to detect the hash type when checking the password ? Can I have passwords with different hashing types stored in the `password` column of the `user` database ?

Comment: No to both questions unfortunately.

Comment: How to deal with such problem then ?

Comment: Force your users to change their passwords upon logging in for the first time.